# How can I set a predefined android-TV device decoder for sound decoding by means of exoplayer?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, exoplayer, android-tv

When I try to play mpeg-2 streams with exoplayer, the video stream plays well, however the sound is mute, Here are debugging details:

[image: Here is debugging details] 
Now, I want to force use of a predefined decoder e.g. OMX.google.mp3.decoder,etc for exoplayer to decode and play mp2 sounds. Can anyone help me to do so? Please include details of the java code. Thanks.